# Como sumar horas, segundos y milisegundos en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, date, datetime

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema, he implementado un cronometro que me calcula hasta milisegundos, el tiempo me lo devuelve en un textview, por lo que es un string.
En algunas ocasiones necesito sumar varios tiempos del cronometro, como convierto mi string con el formato "12:12:34:456" de tal manera de poder sumarlo con otro tiempo de igual formato? 
osea necesito sumar por ejemplo: "12:12:34:456" + "1:23:43:435" y me devuelva el tiempo de lo sumado.

He intentado convertir a dateformat pero no funciona

```
 SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```

formato.parse(Textview.getText().toString());

Comment: el usuario ingresa el tiempo o solo presiona start y comienza la cuenta de 0 y despues lo detiene cuando desea

Comment: el usuario presiona start y marca los "laps" que son las vueltas, formando un listado de tiempos (de tipo string). yo necesito sumar despues esos tiempos del listado para saber el total

Comment: Pasalo todo a milisegundos y realiza la suma en mili , luego lo pasas al formato que deseas.

Comment: Eso estoy haciendo.  Pero estará bien? O habrá otro método que consuma menos recursos?